# webpack-dev-server but what about your regular Node Server?

Tags: javascript, express, webpack

I don't quite get this.  So [webpack-dev-server](https://itnext.io/sort-of-beginners-guide-to-webpack-dev-server-98f8843b1bc1) is supposed to spin up its own node service?  Then how is your site going to work if you have your own expresjs code that the site relies on?  Usually your own expressjs code isn't a few lines.

If it's not using your node service that's usually very custom and has other stuff in it such as possible endpoints (maybe you're getting your data from a json file for now for example) then the webpack-dev-sever won't know about your "other stuff" that you had defined in your ExpressJS instance

I have a few REST endpoints specified in my expressjs instance that need to be there so that it returns data to my site from a few json files that sit local in my project

**here's my real expressjs service**

```
const _ = require('lodash'),
  companyTable = require('./shared/data/companies.json'),
  express = require('express'),
  app = (module.exports = express()),
  history = require('connect-history-api-fallback'),
  oneYear = 31536000;


module.exports = app
  .on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  })
  .get('/api/v1/companies', (req, res) => {
    res.json(
      companyTable.map((company) => {
        return _.pick(company, [
          'id',
          'active',
          'images',
          'locations'
        ]);
      })
    );
  })
  .use(history())
  .use(
    express.static('dist', {
      maxage: oneYear,
    })
  )
  .use((req, res) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,OPTIONS');
    res.header(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json'
    );
    res.send('Sorry, Page Not Found');
  });
```

but if I use `webpack-dev-server` it won't have any of this in it...so my site wouldn't even work

Comment: You can use `webpack-hot-middleware` and `webpack-dev-middleware` instead. https://github.com/lmarqs/simple-php-application/blob/master/src/main/javascript/server.js

Comment: so this is basically just putting a watch on your config really and adding a couple dev stuff like hot loading to it but you are using your real node service in this case